# I have a syntax error when updating list of items when using room ( (1) near "?": syntax error )

Tags: android, sql-update, android-room

my error:

> databaseE/SQLiteLog: (1) near "?": syntax error in "update posts_table
> set list = ?,? where id= ?"

my code:

```
@Query("update posts_table set list = :list where id= :id")
    Completable updatePost(int id, ArrayList<Integer> list);
```

Comment: please put some effort and update your question to make it more clear. It is very hard for people to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write like this

```
@Query("update posts_table set list = :list where id= :id")

void updatePost(ArrayList list,int id);
```

I recommend you to convert the arraylist into string and then add the data in db
don't add direct the arraylist into it